# Embedded font in base64 image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fonts

i gave an svg with some custom fonts (embedded via css's font-face)
In the browser it works fine, but if i try to make a base64 encoded image from the SVG, the font wont be recognise.

[image]

Gere are my codes:

**CSS**

```
    svg,text, textPath{
    font-family: 'MyFont';  
    }

@font-face
{
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;base64,AAEAAAAQA...);
}
```

**JS** im using RaphaelJS

```
//set the text's font
t.attr({"font-family": "MyFont"})

//make the snapshot
    var source = new Image();
    $("body").append(source);
    $('body').click(function(){

        // record start time
        var startTime = new Date();

        var svg = $('#paper').html();

        var mySrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+Base64.encode(svg);

        //source.src = base64Path + "?" + mySrc.slice(5);
        source.src = mySrc;

        var endTime = new Date();

        console.log(endTime - startTime);


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embed the stylesheet in the SVG itself, or reference it externally. A general page stylesheet won't be applied if the SVG is rendered on its own.

Check out [the reference on SVG styling](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS) for more information.